# Creating a patch installer

Tags: java, install4j

I would like to create an install4j project that can:

- Copy some folders from an existing installation to a backup folder (for rollback if needed)
- Install new folders to replace the old.
- Create a rollback installer that would reverse this process.

Basically, a patch installer.

Is there already an example `.install4j` file I can use so I don't have to create all this from scratch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Copy some folders from an existing installation to a backup folder (for >rollback if needed)

This can be done with a "Copy files and directories" action

> Install new folders to replace the old.

This is done by the "Install files" action

> Create a rollback installer that would reverse this process.

As of install4j 9, this is not available. The uninstaller will uninstall all files that the installer and any previous installer have installed, but it cannot roll back to a previous state.